Tableau filtering one column based on match in other column, without the use of parameters
How to Filter a Network Graph in Tableau Public to Show All Related Connections
I’m working on a network graph in Tableau Public and need help setting up a filter that works effectively for my use case. Here's the structure of my data and what I want to achieve:
The structure of my data:
Combination Product Code Id         X   Y   combined sales   Total sales 1   Combined Sales 2
AAA - DDD           AAA  1          50  25  200               2000           
AAA - DDD           DDD  1          50  25  200                              1000
BBB - DDD           BBB  2          70  35  400               1500
BBB - DDD           DDD  2          70  35  400                              1000

Combination represents the lines connecting nodes in the network graph and product Code represents the nodes.
Current Graph Setup:
column shelf: X
Dual Axis row shelf:
- Y: Plots lines (represents the Combination field).
- Y: Plots circles (represents the Product Code field).
Information setting:
- Both Y: Id
Tooltips:
- First Y: Displays Combination and Combined Sales.
- Second Y: Displays Product Code and Total Sales.
enter code here

Problem:
I want to filter the graph based on values in the Product Code field. When I apply the filter, the relevant lines (Combination) should remain visible, even if the selected product code appears on either side of the dash (e.g., in "AAA - DDD"). However, when I currently add a filter on Product Code, only the nodes remain visible, and the lines disappear.
Goal:
I want to filter based on values in the Product Code field, which should filter the Combination field as well, regardless of whether the product name appears before or after the dash. This way, all relevant nodes and lines remain visible when I apply a filter.
Example:
If I select "DDD" in Product Code, the filter should display all rows in the example above.
If I select "BBB" in Product Code, it should display:
Combination Product Code
BBB - DDD   BBB
BBB - DDD   DDD

Does anyone know how I can structure or adjust my data to achieve this type of filtering in Tableau? I also want to add since i have user specific views using row level security, I cant use paramers for any of these fields, so it needs to be done using only filtering.
Screen shot refrence for how the graph is set up:


The trick to complex filtering issues is often to write a boolean valued calculated field that expresses your filter criteria.
So for instance, if you have a parameter that lets you select a single product code, you could make a calculated field named say, Include_Link?,  could be something like
STARTSWITH([Combination], [Product Code Param]) OR ENDSWITH([Combination], [Product Code Param])

Then put Include_Link? on the filter shelf and select the value True
If you have instead a set of Product Codes to work with instead of just one, then you can use a set instead of a Parameter - making the calculation something closer to
LEFT([Combination], 3) IN [Product Code Set] OR RIGHT([Combination], 3) IN [Product Code Set])

